# Imagen docker corriendo por el puerto 80

Tags: ionic, cordova, docker

Hace un par de días que ando trasteando con Docker, os cuento mi intención.

Crear un Dockerfile con:

- LAMP
- Wordpress
- Nodejs
- npm
- ionic-framework
- cordova

Y que desde el puerto 80 usando "localhost" pueda acceder al wordpress.

He montado un Dockerfile en el que funciona todo correcto excepto cuando arranco la imagen, si la arranco para acceder desde consola:

`sudo docker run -i -t nombre_imagen /bin/bash` Todo funciona OK!

Pero si intento arrancarla contra el puerto 80

`sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 nombre_imagen` No arranca :'(

**Os paso el contenido del Dockerfile.**

```
# This is my first Dockerfile

FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Marc Torres <marc.torres@nuclio.com>


# Instalamos dependencias
    # apache2: Servidor Web
    # php5: Lenguaje de programacion PHP
    # php5-mysql: Driver de MySql para PHP
    # supervisor: Lanzadaror y Monitor de procesos
    # wget: Utilidad para obtener archivos via HTTP
    # unzip: Para descromprimir
    # nodejs
    # npm
  RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \
    apache2 \
    php5 \
    php5-mysql \
  #  supervisor \
    wget \
    unzip \
    nodejs \
    npm

# fucking debian installs `node` as `nodejs`
  #RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10

  # mysql-server se instala con intervención del usuario,
  # pero como no es modo interactivo lo que hacemos es setearle las variables
  # con un valor.
  # Para simplificar hemos usado como usuario y contraseña de mysql 'root'
  RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root' | \
    debconf-set-selections && \
    echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root' | \
    debconf-set-selections

  # Procedemos ahora sí, a instalar mysql-server
  RUN apt-get install -qqy mysql-server

  # Preparamos Wordpress
    # Obtenemos la última versión
    # Descomprimimos
    # Copiamos el contenido dentro del root del servidor
    # Removemos el viejo index.html (mensaje de bienvenida de apache)
  RUN wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && \
    tar xzvf latest.tar.gz && \
    cp -R ./wordpress/* /var/www/html && \
    rm /var/www/html/index.html \
    rm -rf /latest.tar.gz

  # descargamos plug-in WP-REST API y lo metemos en la carpeta plugins
  RUN wget https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/json-rest-api.1.2.5.zip
  RUN unzip json-rest-api.1.2.5.zip -d /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/
  RUN rm -rf /json-rest-api.1.2.5.zip

  # ejecutamos a mysql en background y creamos la base de datos llamada wordpress
  RUN (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &); sleep 5; mysqladmin -u root -proot create wordpress

  # Reemplazamos el archivo wp-config.php (más abajo lo creamos) a la carpeta de wordpress
  # Este archivo contiene la configuración de nuestro sitio
  COPY wp-config.php /var/www/html/wp-config.php

  # instalamos git
  RUN apt-get -y install git

  # instalamos ionic en entorno global -g
  RUN npm install -g ionic-framework

  # instalamos cordova de forma global -g
  RUN npm install -g cordova

  #creamos link para evitar errores de node
  RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

  # Le decimos al contenedor que tiene que hacer accesible al puerto 80 (en el que corre HTTPD)
  # para así nosotros poder acceder al mismo desde fuera
  EXPOSE 80
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a añadir tail -f /dev/null a tu comando de la siguiente forma.

```
sudo docker run -d -p 80:80 nombre_imagen tail -f /dev/null
```

Esto ocurre cuando ningún proceso de tu docker se ejecuta en foreground. Echa un vistazo a esta respuesta de Stack Overflow Inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d

Comment: Pues tienes razón, entiendo. Ahora el container arranca, el problema que persiste es que el EXPOSE 80, o el 80:80 no acaba de tirar, al escribir "localhost" en el navegador no ataca al directorio /var/www/html del container. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Si entras dentro del docker está todo corriendo correctamente? Prueba a instalar un curl o alguna herramienta similar dentro del docker y probar dentro.

Comment: Pues si, entrando dentro todo esta OK, funciona todo, git, npm, node...etc... lo único que no acaba de tirar es el EXPOSE en el puerto 80, por lo cual desde el navegador accediendo a "localhost" no muestra nada.

Comment: Y si en vez de localhost pones el nombre de tu hostname? ej: mtorres:80. Mira si así funciona. Si es así, quizás tengas que poner 127.0.0.1:80:80 o 0.0.0.0:80:80 en el -p.  Otra cosa es que tengas el puerto 80 ya ocupado, prueba a bindear en otro puerto.

Comment: Vale, vamos a ver, tonto de mi he comprobado si el apache estaba corriendo, y resulta que no :( he arrancado apache y tachaaan.. funciono...

Muchas gracias por tu aportación anterior, ha sido la clave! Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto es que separes todo en diferentes contenedores, como recomendación utiliza las imagenes oficiales de docker: wordpress, php, node.

Tu problema que no arranca es debido que no estás corriendo un contenedor por servicio. Lo recomendable es que solo corras un servicio por contenedor y los enlaces entre sí con docker-compose.

Lo recomendables es que el stack lo crees con [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted)

Answer (score 0):

En el DOCKERFILE debes declarar que puerto usa con EXPOSE 80
y luego al hacer docker run tienes que usar el parámetro -p :

docker run -d -p 80:80